# Passing variables from VBs to Batch File

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm just struggling with this seemingly simple code:

```
a = objNode.Text


dim WshShell


set WshShell=Wscript.Createobject("Wscript.shell")


 WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Users\c1921\Ayla_Data\ccode.bat " & Chr(34) & a & filename 'this line here does not work right.


 Set WshShell = Nothing
```

The code does almost what I want it to. This is the batch file code:

```
@echo off 

echo test passed variables:

echo %1 

echo %2

pause
```

But echo %1 returns both values and echo %2 returns echo off:

```
219270AC000N000009132
ECHO OFF
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've tried adding extra quotes in this line:

```
WshShell.Run ""C:\Users\c1921\Ayla_Data\ccode.bat "" a & filename 'variation 1

WshShell.Run """C:\Users\c1921\Ayla_Data\ccode.bat """ a & filename 'variation 2

WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Users\c1921\Ayla_Data\ccode.bat " & Chr(34) & a + filename 'variation 3
```

I don't understand what I'm missing here?
Any help in the right direction would be great. If there's any helpful documentation on using vbs and batch that would be great too.

DM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... & a & filename
```

is the problem. You just concatenate the arguments, instead of separating them with a space. That's why the batch file only sees the first argument which contains both at once. `echo %2` will then yield `ECHO is off.` because `%2` is empty.

```
... & a & " " & filename
```

should work. For some values of work, I guess. If either `a` or `filename` contains spaces it'll probably blow up. You can add quotes around them to prevent that:

```
... & Chr(34) & a & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & filename & Chr(34)
```

Then `%1` and `%2` in the batch file will include the quotes, though. To remove them there you can use `%~1` and `%~2` respectively.

Comment: Thank you that did work. The value for `filename` unfortunately is put in by a user into a text file then read. There is a possibility of spaces being accidentally added. If I switch `a` and `filename` (e.g. `WshShell.Run "somefilepath" & filename & " " & a`) would that fix the potential problem? `a` does not ever have spaces.

Comment: You can add quotes around the filename, i.e. `Chr(34)`. That's the usual way of dealing with arguments with spaces.